# Pushing new git changes without checking out master (Xcode/Bitbucket)

Tags: xcode, git, bitbucket, git-merge, git-commit

I'm new to git and I started making changes to a previous commit without creating a new branch. (oops)

Now my local version is no longer the current master. Trying to push the changes gives me the following error: "The current branch could not be determined." If I check out the current master, I can commit as normal, but I lose all the changes I made after the mistake (but save in a backup local copy).

1. How do I push my new changes without checking out the current master? (branch, merge, etc.)
2. Or how do I connect my existing project to a new repository and start over? 
   (I tried changing the repository location to a new url, but I still have to check out the master to push..)

If the answer requires terminal commands, baby steps would be appreciated.

Comment: did you try a git pull and resolve any merge conflicts?

Comment: push and pull give me the same error:  "The current branch could not be determined."

Comment: try a 'git status', have you committed them to your local master

Comment: I committed the changes and assume those are to the local master ("push to remote" is grayed out). When I fetch and refresh status nothing seems to happen and I have the same errors.

Comment: try 'git checkout -b new-branch-name', then push that branch...attempt to merge to master with pull request on server

Comment: checking out the new branch also deletes all my changes..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple solution I use always - when I start developing on the **master** branch and forget to create new branch.

```
1. git stash
2. git checkout -b new-branch-name
3. git stash apply
4. git add *
5. git commit -m "commit"
6. git push origin new-branch-name .
```

That's all :)

Also as you are beginner you should [play and learn git by playing this game](https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/3) and you will solve your problems related git by yourself :)

Comment: Thanks @vrushali. The trygit tutorial helped alot. I went through the steps, but when I got to 'git push' I was asked for a keychain since I hadn't setup SSH. After setting up SSH, I went back through the steps, but I recieved the following messages: "No local changes to save", "nothing to commit, working tree clean" The branch was added to xcode, but nothing has changed in the repository.